# RubyOnRails: a new database request (mysql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have in my upload_controller following function:

```
 def analyse
    (current_user.uploads).perform_analysis        
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to :back }
     end
```

meaning, that perform_analysis will analyse uploads only of one specific user, who is now online, say user A.

perform_analysis is situated in upload model.

```
 def self.perform_analysis
    blablabal
    @upload=Upload.find_by_arraydb_file_name(x)
    @upload.update_attributes(blablabla)
  end
```

x is the name of the upload-file.

My problem is, that by calling this line

```
@upload=Upload.find_by_upload_file_name(x)
```

database has the following request:

```
select upload from uploads  WHERE current_user=user A AND upload_file_name=x
```

I want the request to be only `WHERE upload_file_name=x` without current_user

How can I do it?

Comment: What's wrong with `Upload.where(file__name:x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_user.uploads` brings `WHERE current_user=user`  in sql query.